# How to choose cut off for winsorization/ flooring- capping? What is the impact of variable distribution on the decision

Tags: normality-assumption, winsorizing

To perform logistic regression I wish to winsorize outliers in independent/ explanatory variables by flooring and capping independent variables.
Can you suggest how I should choose cut-off for winsorization, i.e 1 & 99th or something else.
Also is there any impact on decision if the distribution of variable is left/ right skewed and not normal.

Please assume we don't have common knowledge of the variable to choose cut off intuitively.

Comment: This seems to be an unusual (and potentially biased) approach to logistic regression.  Would you have any references recommending and justifying its use?

Comment: Can you explain what is unusual/ biased in my approach.
I know there are outliers in the data. I need help in determining what cut off to use for winsorization.

Comment: (1) Automatically throwing out outliers based on a percentile and (2) winsorizing explanatory variables in regressions are both unusual procedures and require careful justification.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with the capping?  That should help guide us towards a principled solution.

Comment: I don't want my model to be influenced by outliers. For example, manual error by person entering records.

Comment: One idea is to look into the `robustbase::glmrob` function in `R`, which can use methods protecting against outliers in the predictors.

Comment: @Kjetil I was surprised to read your claim, so I tested it and found it not to be true.  The test includes one outlying predictor.  `glmrob` is unable to compensate for its high leverage. `library(robustbase);
x <- c(0:9, 100);
y <- rnorm(length(x), pmin(10, x));
fit <- glmrob(y ~ x, "gaussian");
plot(x, y);
abline(fit)`

Comment: @whuber: The help page for glmrob claims it can do this, see the argument `weights.on.x` (with default value none). It can even take a function as arguments, so can be used as a basis for own implementation. But I didn' test it ... [here](https://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/papers/2003/rousseeuwchristmann-robustnessseparationoutlierslo.pdf) is a promising paper.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you!  I hadn't noticed that option, and it's precisely what is needed.